# Not able to train key_vaule_pairs in azure from recognizer( custom model)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am labeling to custom train invoices. I have leveraged the prebuilt-document model for key-value-pairs. But if I custom train for tables the key-value-pairs is always empty or there is no such option to label key-value-pairs although the documentation says it has support.

If there is a way to label key-value-pairs or if not is there a way to compose prebuilt-document with my custom trained model will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

General Document API is a pretrained model that does not require labeled data. to train a custom model following is one of the approach

### **Build and train a custom model**

***Upload training data***

Need to upload required documents in Azure blob storage container.

[image]

**Create a project in the Form Recognizer Studio**

1. Open [Form Recognizer Studio](https://formrecognizer.appliedai.azure.com/studio)
2. In the Studio, select the **Custom models** tile, on the custom models page and select the **Create a project** button.

[image]

1. On the create project dialog, provide a name for your project, optionally a description, and select continue.
2. On the next step in the workflow, choose or create a Form Recognizer resource before you select continue.

[image]

3. Next select the storage account created to upload custom model training dataset. The **Folder path** should be empty if training documents are in the root of the container. If documents are in a subfolder, enter the relative path from the container root in the **Folder path** field. configure storage account select continue.

[image]

4. Review project settings and select **Create Project** to create a new project.

**Label your data**

1. To start labeling your dataset, create first field by selecting the plus (➕) button on the top-right of the screen to select a field type.

[image]

2. Enter a name for the field.
3. To assign a value to the field, choose a word or words in the document and select the field in either the dropdown or the field list on the right navigation bar.
4. Repeat the process for all the fields you wish to label for your dataset.
5. Label the remaining documents in your dataset by selecting each document and selecting the text to be labeled.

**Train your model**

1. On the train model dialog, provide a unique model ID and, optionally, a description. The model ID accepts a string data type.
2. For the build mode, select the type of model

[image]

3. Select **Train** to initiate the training process.
4. Template models train in a few minutes. Neural models can take up to 30 minutes to train.
5. Navigate to the *Models* menu to view the status of the train operation.

**Test the model**

Once the model training is complete, test model by selecting the model on the models list page.

1. Select the model and select on the **Test** button.
2. Select the + Add button to select a file to test the model.
3. With a file selected, choose the **Analyze** button to test the model.
4. The model results are displayed in the main window and the fields extracted are listed in the right navigation bar.
5. Validate model by evaluating the results for each field.
6. The right navigation bar also has the sample code to invoke model and the JSON results from the API.

[image]